# How does Esau react to Yaakov not coming to Seir (Beraishis 33 (14))?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayishlach, esav

In [Beraishis 33 (14)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.33.14?lang=bi&with=Haamek%20Davar&lang2=en) Yaakov says he will meet up with Esau again in Seir. Rashi points out:

> Therefore he did not go to Seir. But when will he go? In the days of
> the Messiah.

Is there any comment on how Esau felt about Yaakov's non-arrival? Did he view it perhaps as another deception?

Comment: Interesting question. If the answer is, There isn't much about it in Midrashim and such, that may be its own answer. Out of sight, out of mind. Chazal say that the problem began when Yaakov "riled him up" by sending him a message. The problem ends when they separate on pretty good terms.

Comment: What if he understood Yaakov's hint, and is still waiting? Btw our names go together. Anyways many of the kabbalistic meanings explain the entire encounter as Yackov drawing down the lights of Tohu in Tikkun, and the process will only be complete when Moshiach comes, because during the exile "the sheep is great etc", lots of birurim left to do. Maybe Esav understood all this

Comment: @YakkOv what hint? Sounds interesting. BTW, you made me laugh with your comment about your names going together hahaha

Comment: @RabbiKaii yeah lol. Maybe Esav understood the kabbalistic meanings of his statement, that Yackov still has a lot of birurim left to do, until the times of Moshiach (see Torah Ohr fRom the alter Rebbe this parsha,and sefer hasichos 5752, vayishlach , towards section 7 and on)

Comment: @YakkOv Can you please extract the key text from the Alter Rebbe or the sefer hasichos 5752 or better still give an English summary?

Comment: The Hebrew translation is here and here's a snippet that has other references וישלח יעקב מלאכים לפניו אל עשו אחיו ארצה שעיר"72, ששלח להודיעו ש"נגמר ונשלם .. בתכלית השלימות .. הבחי' ומדרגות .. כולם נתבררו ונתקנו כו'"73, והגיע הזמן לילך יחדיו להגאולה74, "אבוא אל אדוני שעירה"75, כמו "בימי המשיח, שנאמר76 (בסיום וחותם ההפטרה דפרשת וישלח) ועלו מושיעים בהר ציון לשפוט את הר עשו והיתה לה' המלוכה"77,  https://www.lahak.org/templates/lahak/article_cdo/aid/3098308/jewish/-.htm

Comment: @YakkOv Maybe your comments could be developed to an answer. Thank you.